# How to determine if the sequence $\sqrt{\pi^n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I determine whether the sequence $a_n = \sqrt{\pi^n}$ converges?

I used the root test and since the limit is 1 the test is inconclusive. What method can I use?

Comment: Is the sequence even bounded?

Comment: The root test is for series, not sequences.  The sequence in question approaches infinity, because $\sqrt{\pi}>1$.

Comment: Hint: $\pi > 1$.

Comment: Thank you @vadim123. I realise now that I haven't fully grasped the differences between sequences and series

Comment: If you do apply the root test, you will get a constant sequence $\sqrt \pi$, whose limit is clearly more than $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, no. The sequence is most definitely not bounded. Note that $\sqrt{\pi^n}=\pi^{n/2}$ and further note that $\frac{n}{2}$ is a strictly increasing function. Since $\pi>1$ then $\pi^{n+k} > \pi^n$ (for $k>0$) and so we are done.

Comment: $a_{n+1}>a_n$ doesn't imply that the sequence is unbounded, e.g., $a_n  = 10 - 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{\pi^n} = {(\sqrt{\pi})^n}$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\sqrt{\pi}>1$$
Hence sequence does not converge.